# Inner product & addition that can make any vector orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an existing inner product, why can't I define this new inner product and new addition operator such that any arbitrary vectors $a$ and $b$ can now be orthogonal:

Let $x$ and $y$ be vectors and $f(x,y)$ be the original inner product and $g(x,y)$ be the new inner product:

Let $g(x,y) = f(x,y)$ where $x \ne a$ and $y \ne b$

$g(a,b) = 0$

$a + x = x$
and
$b + y = y$

So basically everytime we want a couple of vectors to be orthogonal, we can redefine the field and inner product such that addition and inner product treat those numbers as $0$.

This new inner product and vector space seems to satisfy all the definitions.

Comment: "Seems to satisfy all the definitions..." $a+x=x$ already implies that $a=0$. (Set $x=0$.)

Comment: On the other hand, you are right in the sense that, if you pick two *linearly independent* vectors $a,b$, then you can define an inner product $g$ such that $g(a,b)=0$. (Extend the pair $(a,b)$ to a base $(e_1=a,e_2=b,e_3,e_4,\ldots)$ and, for $u=u_1e_1+u_2e_2+\ldots, v=v_1e_1+v_2e_2+\ldots$ define $g(u,v):=u_1v_1+u_2v_2+\ldots$. This proof works in both the finite- and infinite-dimensional vector space.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop yeah so in this case i'm basically defining two zeros

Comment: Identity elements are unique. Say you have two and call them $0_a$ and $0_b$. Then $0_a = 0_a + 0_b = 0_b$ so they're the same number.

Comment: @JobHunter69 You cannot have it both ways. Either you have broken one of the axioms of the vector space, or you cannot have two different zeros. As you have two different zeros, this tells me that you have broken one (or more) of the axioms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but it seems to me that you kind of define two kinds of zeros of the space, which actually cannot happen in a vector space. In other words, if $(V,+,\cdot,g)$ is your new inner product space, you want for every $x,y\in{V}$ to satisfy $a+x=x$ and $b+y=y$. Thus for $x=b$ and $y=a$, you would ask: $b=a+b=b+a=a$ and since you ask for $g(a,b)=0$ you ask for $g(a,a)=0\iff a=0_{U}$ where $U$ is the initial space. But then you would be asking to define $g(x,y)=f(x,y)$ for $x,y\neq0_{U}=0_{V}$ which wouldn't be an inner product as it is not even defined in $V\times V$.